# Spring Batch Solution

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-job-monitoring, spring-batch-stream

1

In our application, we have around 100000 customers and need to process some data on monthly basis. Data processing logic for each customer involves, around 7 rest calls to different service. We need to do this in spring batch to achieve performance.

Steps to process data --l
Read all customers List-get the data web service--l
call 7 different micro services to get the balance, type, fees, date etc etc..--l
Write result to S3 bucket

please suggest the design the flow in spring batch

Answer (score 0):

you can create a flow of multiple steps where for each step you can send "serviceName" as parameter. Write a customReader which calls the service based on serviceName. In CustomReader you can decide on the way you want to call the services.

```
List<Step> steps = new ArrayList<>();
for(each of your service){
 createStep(String serviceName);
}

private Step createStep(String serviceName){
return stepBuilderFactory.get(""service calls")
.reader(UorCustomReader)
.processor(YourProcessor)//if needed
.writer(YourCustomCompositeWriter)
}
```